# Session for multiple users in django

Tags: django, session

I have written a code which generates set of data which gets stored in mysql tables.If a user logsin data is generated and from tables it is displayed.I am using the same table for all the users to store data..I have used sessions..The problem is when a user is logged in already and another user logsin, the data due to previous user is displayed..What is the solution so as have data for a particular user is displayed only when that user logsin?

Comment: can you tell exactly how man tables do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce user_id into your data table and build and filter user data according to the user to have concurrency of multiple users in same time.

Logged in user object can be reached through [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user):

Update:

For instance if you had data as this

```
user_data_row
user_data_row
user_data_row
```

you would now have

```
user_data_row user_id(1)
user_data_row user_id(2)
user_data_row user_id(1)
user_data_row user_id(2)
user_data_row user_id(1)
user_data_row user_id(2)
```

so you can do something as

```
MyObject.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id)
```

Comment: Yes i know that..but the thing is i have created a website for which when user logs in data is displayed in the website.These data is taken from database and displayed in website.

Comment: Just get the data based on users unique KEY from db.